# Why does not Seaborn Relplot print datetime value on x-axis?

Tags: python, plot, time-series, seaborn, kaggle

I'm trying to solve a Kaggle Competition to get deeper into data science knowledge. I'm dealing with an issue with seaborn library. I'm trying to plot a distribution of a feature along the date but the relplot function is not able to print the datetime value. On the output, I see a big black box instead of values.

Here there is my code, for plotting:

```
rainfall_types = list(auser.loc[:,1:])
grid = sns.relplot(x='Date', y=rainfall_types[0], kind="line", data=auser);
grid.fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

Here there is the
[Seaborn.relpot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJSaX.png) and the [head of my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxPhY.png)

Comment: Probably your `Date` column has string values, not datetime objects.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thanks a lot for your reply

Answer (score 2):

I found the error. Pratically, when you use pandas.read_csv(dataset), if your dataset contains datetime column they are parsed as object, but python read these values as 'str' (string). So when you are going to plot them, matplotlib is not able to show them correctly.
To avoid this behaviour, you should convert the datetime value into datetime object by using:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(dataset, parse_date='Column_Date')
```

In this way, we are going to indicate to pandas library that there is a date column identified by the key 'Column_Date' and it has to be converted into datetime object.
If you want, you could use the Column Date as index for your dataframe, to speed up the analyis along the time. To do it add argument `index='Column_Date'` at your read_csv.

I hope you will find it helpful.